# List view threshold for administrator not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, list-view-threshold

My webapplication listview threshold is set to 5000. For administrators it is set to 20000

My list has 6000 items. I have an index on modified date. I create a view sorted on modified. When I open the view I get the message that the listview threshold is exceeded. I am a sitecollection administrator. Should I not see the 6000 items because of the 20000 setting for administrators?

Answer (score 1):

Are you belong to a group that's a member of the local administrators group of the Microsoft SharePoint server?

Did you get this error message "This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator"?

If so, this behavior is by design. Nested group members in the local administrators group aren’t identified as local administrators on the SharePoint Server. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4294330/list-view-threshold-for-auditors-and-administrators-doesn-t-work

Comment: I am in the local admin group of the server. I am sitecollection administrator and I am a farm adminstrator. I get the message This view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold (5000 items) enforced by the administrator. According to https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling/ the setting for administrator is only for code. Not for display.